# How do I reset an object's rotation to its origin

Tags: three.js

A snipped of what I've tried to reset rotation, but this doesn't work:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    mesh.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0));
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function() {
    mesh.rotation.set(0,0,0);
    mesh.updateMatrix();
}, 3000);
```

The object rotates at the lookAt, but doesn't rotate back after 3000ms.

How do I make the mesh reset its rotation as if you just created it?

Answer (score 2):

Put the second timeout inside the first one.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    mesh.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0));

    setTimeout(function() {
        mesh.rotation.set(0,0,0);
        mesh.updateMatrix();
    }, 3000);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: That didn't solve it. It seems the lookAt changes the quaternion and rotation vector but changing the rotation vector doesn't impact the quaternion or something like that?